# Nihilominus and nonetheless, related?

Tags: etymology, english

I find the word *nihilominus* remarkable. Like many Spanish or English words, the meaning can sort of be deduced from the meaning of the words making the composite (e.g. *paraguas* in Spanish, whiteboard in English). As far as my learning of Latin is going, I have not encountered many such composite words in Latin.

Anyway, it came to my mind that *nihilominus* is actually very similar, in terms of composition and meaning, to the English word "nonetheless" (since *nihilo* = nothing and *minus* = less[er]). I cannot find the etymology of the latter though. Are the two words historically related, or both are the mere outcome of an independent [linguistic composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_(linguistics)) process that fortuitously yielded almost identical words, like if one would be the translation of the other?

Comment: Good question! I think the word you're looking for is "calque".

Answer (score 4):

Every source I found (*Random House*, *Online Etymology*, *Wictionary*) said that etymologically it is just a contraction of "none the less". However, that doesn't seem very interesting, because it doesn't address your question in a very satisfying way.

What I found more interesting is the fact that such words may date back to Old English as far back as 900 or earlier. A similar word is *natheless*, whose origin is given in the  given in the *[Collins Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/natheless)* as:

> Old English *nāthylǣs*, from *nā* never + *thӯ* for that + *lǣs* less

From [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/prepositions-youve-never-heard-of/natheless):

> Natheless : nevertheless, notwithstanding
>
> You can spell it natheless or nathless. It's been in use (in various
>   forms) for almost a thousand years, and comes from the Old English
>   phrase nā thē lǣs, meaning "not the less."

I also came across the following:

> “Are these words really that old?” Arlene said.
>
> “Older, even,” I said. “Especially earlier versions of them such as
>   netheless and natheless, which come from Old English, before the years
>   were in triple digits. The phrases got used adverbially so much that
>   they got treated as single words. We don’t use natheless anymore
>   because we don’t use na anymore, but none and the now-archaic use of
>   never the and never a to mean ‘not’ have taken over.”
>   (*[Confessions of a Word Lush](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=9-FiDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA157&lpg=PA157&dq=%22Especially%20earlier%20versions%20of%20them%20such%20as%20netheless%22&source=bl&ots=1GO2P53D0o&sig=3pHHNcBdD6Qla2Xojn6q5QB2fo8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjHnJjk9J_eAhWFDZAKHdYJAmMQ6AEwAHoECAIQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22Especially%20earlier%20versions%20of%20them%20such%20as%20netheless%22&f=false)* By James Harbeck)

Since they date so far back in Old English, I think it's doubtful that their etymology could be tied to Latin.